# labels and the predictions of multiclass images images Index Error: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am training a CNN with an dataset of images that consists of 2410 RGB images and belongs to two categories, i.e., `crops` and another is `grass`. After training the CNN model, it achieved an accuracy for train of 100% and for testing an accuracy of  75%. In addition to this, when I tried to display several images of the dataset with their labels and the predictions, I got an error that is

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My code:

```
# Display some pictures of the dataset with their labels and the predictions
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3, figsize=(10, 10),
                        subplot_kw={'xticks': [], 'yticks': []})

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flat):
    ax.imshow(plt.imread(test_df.Filepath.iloc[i]))
    ax.set_title(f"True: {test_df.Label.iloc[i]}\nPredicted: {pred[i]}")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-6ebcd93c2050> in <module>()
      5 for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flat):
      6     ax.imshow(plt.imread(image_df.Filepath.iloc[i]))
----> 7     ax.set_title(f"True: {image_df.Label.iloc[i]}\nPredicted: {pred[i]}")
      8 plt.tight_layout()
      9 plt.show()

IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I resolve this problem.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvAHw.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure what is going wrong in your script without some more information regarding image_df (i.e. what shape your data is). But as the error indicates, it seems that you're trying to access a list index that is not in the list (trying to get the nth element from a list with less than n elements).  When enumerating through axes.flat, `image_df.Label` needs to have a size equal to or larger than `axes.flat` in order for `image_df.Label.iloc[i]` to be valid. To find out what is happening exactly, you should find out what sizes these lists have.